# Spring boot + axon framework starter + distributed command bus using JGroups

Tags: axon

My current goal is build a project using spring boot starters for testing distributed command using Jgroups.

I got this message when it runs:  Received unknown message: org.axonframework.jgroups.commandhandling.JoinMessage

It comes from org.axonframework.jgroups.commandhandling.JGroupsConnector

```java
    @Override
    public void receive(Message msg) {
        Object message = msg.getObject();
        if (message instanceof JoinMessage) {
            processJoinMessage(msg, (JoinMessage) message);
        } else if (message instanceof JGroupsDispatchMessage) {
            processDispatchMessage(msg, (JGroupsDispatchMessage) message);
        } else if (message instanceof JGroupsReplyMessage) {
            processReplyMessage((JGroupsReplyMessage) message);
        } else {
            logger.warn("Received unknown message: " + message.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

Current POM

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-axon-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-axon-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter-jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

Console output

```
2018-07-20 08:38:01.652  WARN 9439 --- [localhost-29107] o.a.j.commandhandling.JGroupsConnector   : Received unknown message: org.axonframework.jgroups.commandhandling.JGroupsDispatchMessage
```

Application

```java
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
    import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.inmemory.InMemoryEventStorageEngine;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringAxonExampleApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAxonExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EventStorageEngine eventStoreEngine() {
        return new InMemoryEventStorageEngine();
    }
    }


Applications.properties

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/axoncqrs
    spring.datasource.username=1
    spring.datasource.password=1
    server.port=8033
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

    java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    axon.distributed.enabled=true
    axon.distributed.jgroups.bind-addr=GLOBAL
    axon.distributed.jgroups.bind-port=7800
    axon.distributed.jgroups.cluster-name=Axon
    axon.distributed.jgroups.configuration-file=default_tcp_gossip.xml
    axon.distributed.jgroups.gossip.hosts=localhost[12001]
    axon.distributed.jgroups.gossip.auto-start=true
```

It's like there are two classes definition at the same time. I feel lost,   Any clues?

Greetings

Francisco

Comment: That's weird Francisco, cant recall this happening to me when using the JGroups Distributed set up.
Do you mind sharing all the dependencies you're using? That might shed some light on the situation.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: I answered the question, although I am still not positive that'll fix it... 
Additionally though, you can up the Axon Framework version to 3.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that from your `pom.xml` and properties I might something to be amiss.
But, the only thing I am able to guess is that you might have two different versions of the Axon Framework on your classpath / in your Maven repository..
Have you tried removing/clearing out all existing libraries your dependent on and running the application again?

---

**Update**

Bit late to the game, but I notice you are using the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency. Mind you, that Axon Framework at the moment does not play nicely with the devtools, as is marked in [this](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/478) issue for example.
Have you tried removing the dependency to resolving the problem at hand?